# Linux torrent client that can add magnet links via bash

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, bittorrent, magnet-uri

I am trying to make a system that enables me to start a torrent download on my Raspberry Pi. Currently, I have a python program running on my laptop, which transmits a magnet link over TCP to my Raspberry Pi. So, I have a magnet link on my Pi, with which I want to start a download. How could this action be automated in the best possible way, and what torrent client would be best suited for this?

Eirik

Comment: You can [set up a watch directory](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/wiki/RTorrentCommonTasks#Watchadirectoryfortorrents) in rtorrent. They have an example of [automatically adding magnet links](http://wiki.rtorrent.org/MagnetUri#Handling_.22magnet:.22_URIs_via_a_bash_script) through bash.

Comment: Try using Transmission http://www.transmissionbt.com/.

Comment: I think most torrent clients support magnet links. `python -mwebbrowser 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:4KVET...'` should start a download with a torrent client that you have associated with magnet links.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get [Deluge](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/About) running on your Pi? It seems that it can be controlled via [Console and Web UIs](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient).